# Oracle stored procedure called ok from local, but error from dblink

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dblink

I have an Oracle Stored Procedure which compiled with no error, and runs with result I expected. Here's how I call it in local DB :

```sql
variable v_emp_cur refcursor;
  exec my_schema.SP_READ_MEMBER('12345678', '', :v_emp_cur);
print v_emp_cur;
```

It printed result well. However, when I call this SP from another DB, using a dblink, like following :

```sql
variable v_emp_cur refcursor;
  exec my_schema.SP_READ_MEMBER@my_dblink('12345678', '', :v_emp_cur);
print v_emp_cur;
```

It returns this error message :

```sql
BEGIN my_schema.sp_read_member@my_dblink('12345678', '', :v_emp_cur); END;
Error at line 2
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Since my Stored Procedure was compiled w/o error, and returns data from local call, I will expected there is no error in it. But I'm not 100% sure, here's my Stored Procedure :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure my_schema.SP_READ_MEMBER(keywordP in varchar2, birthdayP in varchar2, resultP out sys_refcursor)
is
v_prg_name varchar2(20) := 'SP_READ_MEMBER';
sys_sql    varchar2(1000);


begin
  Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name, '1.0 Start');
  sys_sql :=  sys_sql || 'select a.no, a.name, a.id_no, to_char(a.birthday, ''yyyy/MM/dd'') as birthday, ''REAL member'' as mtype, email, mobile from members  a where 1=1 ';
  if keywordP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || ' and (a.no=''' || keywordP || ''' or a.name=''' || keywordP || ''' or a.id_no=''' || keywordP || ''') ';
  end if;
  if birthdayP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || ' and a.birthday=to_date(''' || birthdayP || ''', ''yyyy/MM/dd'') ';
  end if;

  open resultP for sys_sql;
  Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name, '2.0 Finished w/o error');

  exception
  when others then
  declare
    error_time VARCHAR2(30) := RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD, HH24:MI:SS'));
    error_code NUMBER := SQLCODE;
    error_msg  VARCHAR2(300) := SQLERRM;
  begin
    rollback;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(error_time || ',' || TO_CHAR(error_code) || ',' || error_msg);
    Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name,  error_msg || ', 3.0 ERROR, sql:' || sys_sql);
  end;
end SP_READ_REP;
/
```

How do I fix this problem ?

Any suggestions are welcome~

Answer (score 2):

You hit a restriction. [Cursor variable declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_variable.htm#LNPLS01312) says:

> Using a cursor variable in a server-to-server remote procedure call (RPC) causes an error. However, you can use a cursor variable in a server-to-server RPC if the remote database is a non-Oracle database accessed through a Procedural Gateway.

Workaround might be to move the procedure into your local database and fetch data over the database link.

Comment: Due to some office security policy, I'm not able to fetch data from remote DB over DBLink, that's why I have to put my Stored Procedure into remote DB. Is that any way I can fix this ?

Comment: If there is, I don't know it, sorry.